# Java architectural class design for a real world scenario

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

This is the problem I need to implement it in Java:

A Car can be a Petrol car or a Diesel Car, and a Hybrid Car is plugged with Petrol or Diesel but not both. Also, a hybrid car has the ability to run on electricity, while not using the petrol or diesel at all and it is decided at run time only whether to select electricity or the other fuel source (petrol or diesel as appropriate).

Here I need to implement with OOP concepts in mind for an example when the Hybrid car running in petrol mode method in the petrol type should be invoked as well as if its diesel the diesel class running method should be invoked.

I am very new to OOP and I came up with the following Design I know It's wrong if any one can help me please.

And I tried this with decorator design pattern just correct me if the deign is wrong for the above scenario..

Car Interface

```
public interface Car {
        public void running();
}
```

Petrol Car Class

```
class PetrolCar implements Car{

    public void running() {
        System.out.println("Running in Petrol");
    }

}
```

Diesel Car class

```
public class DieselCar implements Car{

    public void running() {
        System.out.println("Running in Diesel");
    }

}
```

Abstract Hybrid

```
public abstract class Hybrid implements Car{

    Car car;

    public Hybrid(Car car) {
        this.car=car;
    }

    public void running(){
        car.running();
    }

    abstract void hybridRunning();

}
```

Implementing Hybrid class

```
public class HybridCar extends Hybrid{

    public HybridCar(Car car) {
        super(car);
    }

    @Override
    void hybridRunning() {
        System.out.println("Running in Hybrid Mood");
    }

}
```

Testing as at run time user can select whether the car is hybrid petrol or hybrid diesel or petrol or diesel...

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String neededType = "Petrol";
        boolean hybrid = true;

        if (hybrid) {
            Hybrid hCar=null;
            if (neededType.equalsIgnoreCase("Petrol")) {
                hCar=(Hybrid)new HybridCar(new PetrolCar());    
            } else if (neededType.equalsIgnoreCase("Diesel")) {
                hCar=new HybridCar(new DieselCar());
            }
            hCar.hybridRunning();
            hCar.running();
        } else {
            Car car=null;
            if (neededType.equalsIgnoreCase("Petrol")) {
                car=new PetrolCar();
            } else if (neededType.equalsIgnoreCase("Diesel")) {
                car=new DieselCar();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Is this Correct is there any short of issues regarding to OOP best practice

Comment: I would have one class `Car` and a `enum Fuel` with a EnumSet of  Petrol, Diesel, LPG, Hydrogen, Electric. e.g. it is common to have LPG and Petrol, or Petrol and Electric.

Comment: @Peter Or even [exclusively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Leaf).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Solar even https://www.worldsolarchallenge.org/

Comment: Your initial concept is okay but will become cumbersome to maintain when you are looking to expand on the concept.  (i.e. trucks, vans, automatic, manual gear shifting, number of tires...etc.)  As @PeterLawrey has shown fuel type is an attribute of the vehicle and with their design you gain assurances of the fuel type you are associating with the object.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jaco0646 No! According to the author the code doesn't appear to work (`I know It's wrong`). Broken code is off-topic at Code Review. Don't recommend possibly broken code to Code Review, ever.

Comment: @Mast, the code appears to work. The OP knows the design is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a single class with an EnumSet of fuels.

```
public interface Car {
    static Car create(Fuel fuel, Fuel... others) {
        return new CarImpl(EnumSet.of(fuel, others));
    }

    Set<Fuel> fuels();
    void running();

    enum Fuel {
       Petrol, Diesel, LPG, Hydrogren, Electric
    }
}
```

Without using an Enum you would use an immutable class.

```
public interface Car {
    static Car create(Fuel fuel, Fuel... others) {
        Set<Fuel> fuels = new HashSet<>();
        fuels.add(fuel);
        Collections.addAll(fuels, others);
        return new CarImpl(fuels);
    }

    Set<Fuel> fuels();
    void running();
    void setMode (Fuel fuel) throws IllegalArgumentException;
     Fuel getMode ();

    class Fuel {
       private final String name;
       public Fuel(String name) { this.name = name; }
       public String name() { return name; }
       public String toString() { return name(); }
       public int hashCode() { return name().hashCode(); }
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           return o instnaceof Fuel && ((Fuel) o).name().equals(name());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I would use a single class with an EnumSet of fuels." Wait until you need to get your car to a mechanic(/electrician) and suddenly the distinction between fuels they use is not enough any more to deal with a single car class.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Then it should be expanded.  Include enums for every aspect of the car and what it could become.  Though, honestly, at this point; we might as well just build a vin decoder and let the manufacturer do this for us.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I agree. I would wait until you need more than one class before adding another class. ;)

Comment: @SusannahPotts good point. I would rather add a field or two than more classes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey
 I guess you did not get my question sharply or I didnt get your answer sharply Can you please implement the CarImpl class as well to check weather it full fill my intention.

Comment: @DjMaxBrington sure. Give me a few hours as I have a meeting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I pretty much like your way.. but th Enum. Is there any other way we can do without using an enum? Most of the time an enum can cause much problems, when we don't know the complete set of possibilities beforehand right?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne using an `enum`1 is usually either a) easy, or b) not possible, e.g. as you say if you don't know them in advance. I have added an answer using a class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanx (Y) :))

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want CarImpl class to check whether it meets the requirement pleas thanks in advance..

Comment: @DjMaxBrington can you clarify what your requirements are? It appears you can only be in a mode of use which match a fuel which is available. Is that right?

Comment: @PeterLawrey the basic thing that I expecting was to re use the method in the PetrolCar calss when the HybridCar is in the Petrol Mode as like as if it's diesel hybrid re using the Diesel cars running method if it's in the deisel mode...

Comment: @DjMaxBrington so we need a setMode method which checks it's an allowed fuel and a running method. You shouldn't expose implementation  details to the caller unless you have to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you please go with full implementation for my requirement no matter even the requirement is correct or wrong thanks for your great help